# how to create button and image view in class that extend view?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a class that extend activity and that get its view in this way:

```
    setContentView((View) viewClass);
```

viewClass is class that extends from view.

I need to implement some button and image view in this class. but how?

Comment: why don't you set activity's content view from xml?

Comment: what do you intend to achieve?

Comment: you will have to override onDraw and then draw your button and image, for getting events on button, you will have to check inside touchlistener whether the pressed co-ordinates lie inside the button area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extends your custom view from ViewGroup or kind of layout for example LinearLayout, this will help you to adding another views to your layout programmatically from activity like :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(view);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("asas");
    view.addView(tv);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

let your main activity be as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        MyView view;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
            view=new MyView(ctx);
            setContentView(view);
        }
    }
```

and let your view class extend any container layout.

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("hello");
        tv.setId(1);

        Button b = new Button(context);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
        b.setText("Hi");
        b.setId(2);

        this.addView(tv);
        this.addView(b, params1);

    }
}
```

Comment: that class has this : public viewClass(Context context,AttributeSet attr){} it has AttributeSet  parameter too. thanks for your help. above answer solved my problem.